# How can difficulty removing lenses from a Canon Rebel T5 be fixed?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, repair

I recently noticed that it's becoming difficult to remove lenses. The lens release button is difficult to depress. I have to press it hard and move my thumb around to get it to release.

The cameras has no serious damage, but has gotten heavy use in the last 2 years. I recently noticed a bit of rust on the lens ring, and think that may be related to this problem.

It's no longer under warranty.

I suspect it won't be too long before it becomes impossible to remove lenses. Any advice for fixing it?

Comment: Not under warranty. Has no serious damage, but has gotten heavy use in the last 2 years.  I recently noticed a bit of rust on the lens ring, and think that may be related to this problem.  Per advice below a tiny drop of oil on the release pin seems to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

The best advice is to send camera to service center and let professionals to deal with the problem. For me this seems like mechanical problem and to reach this area you need to disassemble a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The lens release button causes a locking pin to drop into the flange.

- With the lens off, press the pin down with a toothpick. If the pin is difficult to press down, the pin itself may be damaged or obstructed.
- With the pin still pressed down, press the button. If the button is difficult to press, the button is likely obstructed.
- If neither of the above occurs, the pin may not be moving freely because of excess friction. A *minuscule* amount of oil around the pin *may* help. (About as much as will lightly coat the tip of the toothpick.)

On some EF adapters, the pin can be accessed after the flange is removed from the front. I have not tried with a camera, but would expect it to be similar. However, **it is probably best to take your camera to a service center**, as [Romeo Ninov advises](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/101446/75526). Taking it in sooner, while the flange can still be accessed from the front, would likely make it easier and less costly to repair.

If you feel it is not worth the repair costs, another option you *might* consider is gluing the pin down permanently. Lenses would no longer lock in place, but they should still work normally. The mount should have enough friction that the risk of lenses detaching during normal use should be minimal.

Comment: Good advice, thanks.  I already carefully put a tiny drop of bicycle chain oil on the pin and worked it in (Disclaimer: I'm not recommending this treatment to anyone).  It seems to be working better now.  I suppose time will tell, but paying for professional service for this Rebel T5 doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: Since rust seems to be a contributor, keeping the pin lightly oiled *may* prevent further rusting.  However, dust can accumulate in the oil, potentially making the problem worse.